# Option Strict On Getting items from lstBox using loop and index

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to assign an item in a list box to a variable at a specific index with a loop with Option Strict On.  its givin me the error "Option Strict On Disallows Late Binding." Error is at **strSelected = lstCart.SelectedItem(index).ToString()**
*The loop basically needs to take each item in the list box, remove the first 20 characters(the name) and then trim the rest(the result is a price), then convert it to an integer using tryparse, then add it to the subtotal.  After the program does this it displays the price in lblSub.Text*

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Public Class Form1

Dim dblSubTotal As Double
Dim dblPrices() As Double = {4.99, 2.49, 6.49, 5.99, 11.99, 8.99, 4.49, 6.99, 0.99, 2.99}
Dim dblShipping As Double
Const SALES_TAX As Double = 0.04
Dim dblTax As Double

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lstCds.Items.Add(("GardenKnomez").PadRight(20) & "- Across The Lawn")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("The Pastries").PadRight(20) & "- Escape The Police")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("Road Wasp").PadRight(20) & "- B Flat")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("Paper Plated").PadRight(20) & "- Just Throw Us Away")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("Exploding Bunions").PadRight(20) & "- Walk It Off")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("NeverFart").PadRight(20) & "- Be Careful What You Wish For")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("Hoth").PadRight(20) & "- In Michigan")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("Naked Nation").PadRight(20) & "- Mabe SomeDay")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("Poopsa").PadRight(20) & "- Pizza")
    lstCds.Items.Add(("Hidden Valley").PadRight(20) & "- It's Only Ranch")
    lstCds.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim strArtist As String
    Dim intIndexSelected As Integer = lstCds.SelectedIndex

    If lstCds.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please make a selection... preferably Exploding Bunions")
    Else

        strArtist = lstCds.SelectedItem.ToString
        strArtist = strArtist.Remove(20)
        strArtist = strArtist.Trim()

        lstCart.Items.Add((strArtist).PadRight(20) & dblPrices(intIndexSelected).ToString("C2"))

        'Display Sub Total
        dblSubTotal += dblPrices(intIndexSelected)
        lblSub.Text = dblSubTotal.ToString("C2")

        'Display Tax
        dblTax = dblSubTotal * SALES_TAX
        lblTax.Text = dblTax.ToString("C2")

        'Display Shipping
        If lstCart.Items.Count >= 5 Then
            dblShipping = 5
        ElseIf lstCart.Items.Count > 0 AndAlso lstCart.Items.Count < 5 Then
            dblShipping = lstCart.Items.Count
        End If
        lblShipping.Text = dblShipping.ToString("C2")

        'Display Total
        lblTotal.Text = (dblSubTotal + dblTax + dblShipping).ToString("C2")
        lstCds.SelectedIndex = -1
        lstCart.SelectedIndex = lstCart.Items.Count - 1

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click

    Dim intIndex As Integer

    If lstCart.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Theres absolutely nothing in your cart, if you want to exit" &
                        " click ""FILE"" then click ""Exit""", "Discount Bin",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf lstCart.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Are you ok?  You have nothing selected in your cart.", "Discount Bin",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        lstCart.Items.RemoveAt(lstCart.SelectedIndex)
        lstCds.SelectedIndex = 0



        'subtract removed from subtotal
        intIndex = lstCart.Items.Count - 1
        dblSubTotal = 0
        Dim strSelected As String
        Dim dblSelected As Double
        For index As Integer = 0 To intIndex
            strSelected = lstCart.SelectedItem(index).ToString()
            strSelected.Remove(0, 20)
            strSelected.Trim()
            Double.TryParse(strSelected, dblSelected)
            dblSubTotal += dblSelected
        Next index
        lblSub.Text = dblSubTotal.ToString("C2")

        'subtract removed from tax


    End If

End Sub

Private Sub mnuFileExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileExit.Click
    If lstCart.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Dim strPrice As String = lstCart.SelectedItem.ToString
        strPrice = strPrice.Remove(0, 20)
        strPrice = strPrice.Trim
        strPrice.Insert(0, "$"c)
        MessageBox.Show("We hope you enjoy your cd's because they're all pretty terrible," &
                        " especally the one for " & strPrice)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("YOU'LL THANK YOURSELF LATER")
    End If
    Application.Exit()
End Sub

Private Sub mnuFileSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileSave.Click
    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter
    If lstCart.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You dont have any items in your cart lol", "Discount Bin",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    Else
    outFile = IO.File.CreateText("ThoseCdsYouWishYouNeverBought.txt")
    For index As Integer = 1 To lstCart.Items.Count
        lstCart.SelectedIndex = index - 1
        outFile.WriteLine(lstCart.SelectedItem)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Reciept printed to your bin directory, your gunna need that.", "Discount Bin",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    outFile.Close()
    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to keep shopping?", "Discount Bin",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.No Then
        Application.Exit()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lstCart_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lstCart.MouseDown
    lstCds.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: generally you have to cast the item back from Object to whatever it is.  you dont say what you put in the listbox nor where the error is, but I suspect it is `strSelected = lstCart.SelectedItem(index).ToString()`

Comment: im sorry yes that is where the error is.

Comment: still dont know what you put in there, but use `CType` to convert it back - `thisItem = CType(lstCart.SelectedItem, ItemClass).PropertyName`.  SelectedItem is not indexed so that looks wonky too.

Comment: so for "thisItem" i replace that with strSelected.  And what do i use for "ItemClass".  Ill just post the whole code up above^^

Comment: **what did you put in the listbox?**  was it just strings, or some class objects?

Comment: just strings, i just updated the post to include all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is incorrect:

```
    Dim strSelected As String
    For index As Integer = 0 To intIndex
        strSelected = lstCart.SelectedItem(index).ToString()
    Next index
    lblSub.Text = dblSubTotal.ToString("C2")
```

SelectedItem is a single object, so you cant index it.  to loop thru the SelectedItemS:

```
  Dim n As Integer = 0 to lstCart.SelectedItems.Count - 1
      strSelected = lstCart.SelectedItems(n)
      ' this is pointless because you do nothing with it
  Next n
```

You can put class objects in the listbox, in which case when getting them back you need to convert/cast the Item object back to the correct `Type` (this is usually the case with that error message):

```
 strName = CType(lstCart.SelectedItem, ItemClass).PropertyName
```

this would convert an object stored as the SelectedItem back to the Class type, so its props can be referenced. your code is a perfect candicate for a class - it would keep the name and price together rather than having to look things up in other arrays.  As soon as you sort the listbox, the indicies no longer match and Gnomes points to the price for Garden Weasel

**Edit**

To remove the selected items:

```
 For n as Integer = lstCart.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
     ' MUST loop backwards
     lstCart.Items.Remove(lstCart.SelectedItems(n)
 Next n
```

after the purge, reloop to recalc instead of subtracting.

Comment: so in my case what would i put for ItemClass?  I tried object and string, its not letting me.  And is strName a new variable or is that supposed to be StrSelected?

Comment: updated code again ^^ i coded the loop the best i can(because i cant run the program) but anyways basically it removes the name off of each item in the list, then trims each one and turns the price into a double, finally it adds them up and the program ultimately displays them in lblSub.Text

Comment: thanks for your patience i got a little confused there, it works perfectly now.  Just out of curiosity why must the loop run backward?